# AWS Cloudformation tools or .Net SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I am trying to automate infrastructure deployment today,Which is better to use.

Any disadvantages if I go with Cloud formation template model?

Answer (score 1):

After some further study,found this question is moot since with SDK you get lot more functionality including initializing and managing cloud formation templates